# Python script - Find folders modified on one host, makes a copy of them on another host via ssh

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I have two systems A (local) and B (remote). A is connected to B via ssh. I'd like to run a python script on A that connects to B and checks the content of the newly created/modified folders (in this example within last 45 minutes) and make a copy of those folders on specified path at A.

I could have wrote the script below which does the same job at one machine but it needs to be local (you execute this script on A, it checks the assigned path for modified directories within last 45 minutes and makes a copy of them on the same machine A at specified path)

How can I extend this script for aforementioned scenario?

```
import os
from shutil import copytree 
from time import time

def mins_since_mod(fname):
"""Return time from last modification in minutes"""
return (time() - os.path.getmtime(fname)) / 60

PARENT_DIR = '/home/A/Desktop'
MOVE_DIR = '/home/A/Updated_Folders'

# Loop over files in PARENT_DIR
for fname in os.listdir(PARENT_DIR):
# If the file is a directory and was modified in last 45 minutes
     if os.path.isdir(fname) and mins_since_mod(fname) < 45:
       copytree(fname, MOVE_DIR) # move it to a new location
```

Comment: Even if you have any suggestion on how to do it via shell script, it is appreciated since the only important thing for me is this to be done no matter with what language

Comment: `rsync` is the tool most frequently used for such things...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rdiff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rdiff-backup) to backup modified files from one server to another.

You can find steps to go about it [here](http://bencane.com/2013/05/20/securely-backing-up-your-files-with-rdiff-backup-and-sudo/)